# Approve first when submit the form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using the PHP CodeIgniter framework.

The problem is that I want the user to check those fields that they have entered and approved by selecting checkbox then submitting the form.

Like these are the fields.

```
<tr>    
    <td>Remarks </td>
    <td><textarea name="particular" rows="3" class="save_record autosuggestship"></textarea></td>   
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>                 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Custom Reference No.</td>
    <td><input type = 'text' name = 'custom_ref_no' class = 'save_record autosuggestship' id="custom_ref_no" /></td>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td><input name = 'costom_date' type = 'text' class = 'save_record date_class autosuggestship' id="costom_date" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <p> Container Information </p>
    </td>
    <td>
```

---

And this the Checkbox to approve.

```
<tr>
    <td>Approve</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="Approve" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This can be done using simple Javascript functions but not to be sure enough about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Should it work when client does not support Javascript (or something)? Is it ok if some browsers will bypass this? If you need to be sure then do checking at server side.

Answer (score 1):

Uses jQuery: try inserting this in your page wrapped in `<script></script>` tags and including jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form input[type=submit]').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if($('#Approve').attr('checked') == 'checked') {
        $('form').submit();
      }
      else {
        alert('You must check the Approve checkbox to continue!');
      }
    });
    // if the user presses enter.
    $('form').on('keyup', function(e) {
      if(e.which == 13) {
       $('form').submit();
      }
    });
});
```

In PHP (make sure you give your input a `name="Approve"`:

```
if(isset($_POST['Approve']) {
  // they have ticked the checkbox.
}
```

Comment: This wont work if user hits enter... change `$('form input[type=submit]').on('click'` to `$('form').submit(function(e){...`

Comment: Please assume that Javascript is turned off.

Comment: Well no because when you trigger the submit, you'll find yourself in a loop!

Comment: @EdHeal it says jQuery in his tags.

Comment: Okay okay, also change `$('form').submit();` to `return true` :) or move `preventDefault()` before `alert`... Then it handles all events that triggers submit, keypress, mouse, whatever..

Comment: @tomhallam - You must not trust anything from the browser

Answer (score 1):

### How to do it using jQuery:

This is not foolproof as browser can always decide to not run this js piece but still useful as it informs user before submitting form (and waiting for server response) so this is mainly for saving some bandwidth as this prevents useless requests to server.

`Useless requests` means here HTTP request (form submit) that returns message asking user to tick one checkbox and then submit same data again.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Catch submit events:
    $('form').submit(function() {
        // Check if checkbox is checked:
        if ($('#checkme').is(':checked')) {
            // Allow form submit:
            return true; 
        } else {
            // Prevent form submit:
            alert('You must check the Approve checkbox to continue!');
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

#### See `<form>` example under *How to do it using PHP* heading.

Client side solution above is based on *tomhallam*'s answer, modified it to be a bit smaller, simpler, complete, and follows a little better jQuery recommendations.

### How to do it using PHP:

It is always good to do same checks at server side, using PHP in this case. Server side checking guarantees that values are really checked no matter if client lacks support for Javascript or any other client side checking methods defined by server.

```php
<?php
/* POST($key) returns value of $_POST($key) if set, 
 *  otherwise empty string is returned. */
function POST( $key ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST[$key] )) return $_POST[$key];
    else return '';
}

if ( isset( $_POST['checkme'] )) {
    // Checkme is checked, do something with form data:
    mySql_insert_formdata( $_POST );
    $_POST['error'] = 'Form processed, thanks for your data';
} elseif ( isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    // Form submitted but checkme not checked, set error message
    $_POST['error'] = 'Checkme must be cheked first!';
}

echo POST('error');
?>

<form action="forms.php" method="post">
    <!-- Hidden field to check at server if form is submitted -->
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="anything" />
    <!-- Some fields for user to fill, POST() inserts previous value if any -->
    <label for="email">eMail</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo POST('email'); ?>" /><br/>
    <!-- Checkbox that must be checked -->
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkme" name="checkme" />
    <label for="checkme">Approve</label><br/>
    <!-- And submit button -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

### Combine client side and server side solutions:

Javascript (client side) solution is not guaranteed to do anything, it depends on browser settings and javascript support.
PHP (server side) solution is guaranteed to do work and client/browser can't change this.

However, I think that it is good to have both of them so whenever Javascript is supported client gets instant notification about problem and does not have to wait for server processing.
And when user does not have JS support then he must wait for server while it checks form and either uses data or returns `"try again"` error.

Answer (score 0):

use the form onsubmit event handler

```
<form onsubmit="return this.Approve.checked?true:alert('must approve!'),false">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Approve</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="Approve" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

instead of the inline code you can use a function, dont forget to leave the inline "return myfunc()" because the form submit will depend on that return, if true the form is submited else it just waits.

Comment: this is html standard, however javascript must be active for it to work. So you must double check it on the server side for that Approve check in case js is not active.